# Bluetooth terminates calls

Tags: samsung, settings, bluetooth, calls, samsung-galaxy-s-9

My Samsung S9 terminates phone calls or streaming when I turn off connected device.
How do I stop this happening? Its most annoying when I park my car abd have to call back due to disconnection.

Comment: Since the phone call is routed to my car when connected, I have never tried this.  Why would I want to risk losing the call ?